# How to configure socket.io client for backend access

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io, quasar-framework

I've made a simple web app that consists on a nodejs scheduler backend and a quasar spa frontend that connects using socket.io.
I know how to configure the client to connect on localhost, but if I try to open the same frontend on another device on the network, logically can't connect.
Taking into account that I will host both server and client on a docker container, how I can configure socket.io to be reachable outside localhost?

Backend:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http')
  .createServer(app)
  .listen(config.socketPort, config.socketIP, function() { // Being: 0.0.0.0:3002
    console.log(
      `socket: websocket listening on ${config.socketIP}:${config.socketPort}`
    );

    const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
      cors: {
        origin: '*'
      },
    });
...
```

Frontend:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002')

export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.prototype.$socket = socket
}
export { socket }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using localhost in your client/frontend code. Here you need to use server ip or domain.

**Edit**
Frontend code app is hosted in a server just to give the user the possibility to get it. After that, browser will load it and execute its code. Here the socket io client needs the exacts address where to find the backend. For example if we leave it localhost, after we download the app from server, it will try to connect to localhost but it wont find the backend app locally because it is in your server. That is why you need to place ip or domain instead of localhost as the backend address.

Comment: Of course, but if server ip is supposed to change on every install, and users aren't supposed to alter the sources, how to do it? Is there something like an env in quasar that holds the servers ip?

Comment: @Sergio Server ip should be static. In client you need to put domain or server ip. You cannot have a server with dynamic ip. Of course you may have a domain with a dynamic ip and a third party service which updates the ip to domain after it detects ip change but this is not ideal.

Comment: Why? This is a selfhosted application, not a cloud service. Am I supposed to know how users do configure their servers?
I would expect Quasar, or any other Vue framework that executes on client, to receive at least the origin ip in an environment var, or something alike.

Comment: Apps made using js frameworks run in client side. In this case they are served by the server(server provides just the bundle as it is). So when your app is downloaded by the browser and loads, the socket io needs to know the ip or domain address where the backend server is hosted in order to be able to connect.
@Sergio